# Gitlab CI не создает раннеров

Tags: git, администрирование, gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция

GitLab 8.0.4
GitLab Shell 2.6.5
GitLab API v3
GitLab CI v5.2.0
Ruby 2.1.6p336
Rails 4.1.12

При регистрации runner'a выдает следующее:

```
Registering runner as cltan115 with registration token: %длинный токен%, url: http://localhost:3000.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

В /home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/config/application.yml:

```
development:
  gitlab_server_urls:
    - 'http://localhost:3000'
  gitlab_ci:
    host: localhost
    port: 9000
    https: false
test:
  gitlab_server_urls:
    - 'http://demo.gitlab.com/'
  gitlab_ci:
    host: localhost
    port: 80
    https: false
production:
  gitlab_server_urls:
    - 'http://localhost:3000'
  gitlab_ci:
    host: localhost
    port: 9000
    https: false
```

Я не нашел больше упоминаний порта 3000, и, думаю, где-то тут и кроется проблема. Но я не знаю, где еще можно указывать 3000 порт, и к чему конкретно его привязывать.
В логах пусто (или я не знаю, куда смотреть - в руби и гитлабе профан).
Есть смутное ощущение, что проблема связана с [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460224/gitlab-ci-invalid-credentials).

Comment: желательно разбить два несвязанных друг с другом вопроса на (сюрприз!) два отдельных вопроса. количество нажатий на кнопку «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы не лимитировано ничем (кроме здравого смысла), а вот содержимое должно соответствовать принятой здесь схеме: «один вопрос — один (и более) ответов».

Comment: Я не уверен, что они не связаны. Здесь что-то куда-то не доходит.
По одной причине, или по разным - неизвестно.
Ах да.
netstat -a | grep 3000 ничего не выдает

Comment: *Я не уверен, что они не связаны* — сошлитесь на контекст другого вопроса. это никоим образом не предосудительно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неверный токен.
Правильный токен берется не из git.example.com/ci/admin/runners , а из http://ci.example.com/admin/runners